# IntelliJ commit window is convinced my JAVA_HOME/PATH is not set for Java

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use the built in commit window in IntelliJ-IDEA Ultimate. This project is a Kotlin project that uses Gradle as the build tool. I have some pre-commit hooks setup to run a detekt check and a license update. When I press the commit button the error i get is the following:

```
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I do have a working JAVA_HOME set and when I run `echo $PATH` my JDK installation can, in fact, be found in the path.

```
nocomment@laptop: ~/Documents/watchdog $ echo $PATH
/home/nocomment/bin:/home/nocomment/.local/bin:/home/nocomment/.cargo/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Right there, `/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin` where i have the package `jdk17-openjdk` installed from the Arch Linux repositories.

Gradle is set up to you the `/usr/lib/jvm/default` path in IntelliJ and the project default is this path as well..

I've looked around on here and elsewhere and tried reinstalling the JDK, running `archlinux-java fix` to no avail.

If anyone knows how to fix this that would be awesome.

Thanks :)

Comment: Personally I don't like symlinks in env vars. I think you should delete that jvm path and *prepend* the *actual* path. I personally like to set `JAVA_HOME` first, then prepend `$JAVA_HOME/bin` Of course, some software ignores JAVA_HOME but anyway...

Comment: I'm back on my home machine now and I actually do this on here, yet it still doesn't work. IntelliJ does not normally ignore this it's only a recent thing

Comment: Try starting IntelliJ from the command line

Comment: I'm having a similar issue where I've added JAVA_HOME using SDK MAN from ~/.zprofile. From the terminal JAVA_HOME is set as well as a variable "DEBUG_NON_LOGIN_SHELL" that is set in ~/.zprofile, and it prints from my Intellij git precommit hook. But the JAVA_HOME env has been removed! I can only assume that Intellij removes it. Then it defaults to jdk8, but I need jdk11 for googleJavaFormat.

Comment: LOL, it seems I had followed this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-19/Shell-Environment-Loading a while back.